# Ansible assign hostname using inventory items

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to assign hostname to a few hosts, gathering it from inventory.

My inventory is:

```
[masters]
master.domain.tld

[workers]
worker1.domain.tld
worker2.domain.tld

[all:vars]
ansible_user=root
ansible_ssh_private_key_file=~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

The code I'm using is:

```yaml
- name: Set hostname
  shell: hostnamectl set-hostname {{ item }}
  with_items: "{{ groups['all'] }}"
```

Unfortunately, code iterate all items (both IPs and hostnames) and assigns to all 3 hosts the last item...

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Don't `loop`: this is going through all your hosts on each target. Use only the natural inventory loop and the `inventory_hostname` special var.

Moreover, don't use `shell` when there is a [dedicated module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/hostname_module.html)

```yaml
- name: Assign hostname
  hosts: all
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:
    - name: Set hostname for target
      hostname:
        name: "{{ inventory_hostname }}"
```